# Rails. How to download data via send_data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to download binary data. I've tryed `send_data` method but it saves **whole** .html page.
I cannot access `send_data` method out of controllers so I declared helper_method in app controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  helper_method :save_data

  def save_data
    send_data('Hello, pretty world :(', :type => 'text/plain', :disposition => 'attachment', :filename => 'hello.txt')
  end

end
```

What I do wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Where are you calling `save_data`?

Comment: @IdanArye in one of my views. Say pages/home.erb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a reason `send_data` is only usable from a controller - it's because it doesn't make sense to use it from anywhere else. `send_data` is performed **instead** of rendering a view, so if you call it from a view, by the time Ruby reaches the command it already started writing the rendered view into the response, and that's why you get the full HTML page.

You need to make it a controller method. Once you have a route for it, you can use the helper for that route to put **a link** to that controller method in your view - not the file data itself.

Answer (score 1):

You must call `send_data` instead of rendering a view. Making this a helper method and calling it from a view does not make any sense at all.

In short: You must have a controller method that `send_data` and has no view:

```
class TextController < ApplicationController
  def hello
    send_data('Hello, pretty world :(', 
              :type => 'text/plain', :disposition => 'attachment', :filename => 'hello.txt')
  end 
end
```

In your view you just have a normal link to that text#hello route.